# What does "somevar >> 0" mean?

Tags: javascript, operators

What does the notation `somevar >> 0` mean in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: `>>` is [bitshifting](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/arithmet.htm#shift) but I don't know why you would bitshift by 0 (unless there is some side effect that I am unaware of, it would do nothing...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `a >> b`, `>>` is a bitwise operator that shifts `a` in binary representation `b` (< 32) bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 3):

[Bitwise right shift](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsoprrshift.htm). Although `somevar >> 0` looks weird.

Comment: It’s sort of confusing, though, since the only numeric type is the double.

Comment: @Gumbo, becuase `somevar >> 0` is equal to `somevar`

Comment: @dheerosaur Not necessarily: `34359739705 >> 0 == 1337`.

Comment: @jleedev: how's that? I mean, how does a 0 bits shifting derives in a different value?

Comment: @jleedev, Oh, thanks. So, it converts the first operand to a 32 bit integer and shifts. Is that right?

Comment: @Tomas Narros: The [Signed Right Shift Operator (`>>`)](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.7.2) is only specified for signed 32 bit integers. So `34359739705 & 0x8FFFFFFF` is performed to get a signed 32 bit integer. And `34359739705 & 0x8FFFFFFF === 1337`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bitwise operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) 
In this case, for shifting the first operand in binary representation the number of bits to the right specified in the second operand, discarding bits shifted off.

<strike>With a `0` as second operand, I guess it has no effect (shifting 0 bits, is getting the same value?).</strike>

I was wrong with this last. As explained at [this @Gumbo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437169/in-javascript/4437186#4437186).