# What does the >> operator do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [>> in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437169/in-javascript)

I'm going through some code and I ran into 2 weird operators: `>>` and `<<`,
in the form of `2<<3` and `442132132>>546542132`.

I deduced that `x<<y` means `x` times `2` in the power of `y`. Meaning, `4<<3` is `4*(Math.pow(2,3))`, which is `32`, but I couldn't find what `x>>y` means.

I know it usually returns `0` for small numbers, but when high numbers are involved, the result is usually a small number.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437169/in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-operators-do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> Left shift    a << b  Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to
>   the left, shifting in zeros from the right. 
> Sign-propagating right
>   shift a >> b  Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the
>   right, discarding bits shifted off.

`442132132>>546542132` seems excessive for a number that is only 32 bits wide.

Answer (score 6):

The [`>>` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.3E.3E_(Sign-propagating_right_shift)) bit-shifts the left value by the right one.

`a >> b` is equivalent to `parseInt(a / Math.pow(2, b))`.

For example:

```
 1 >> 0 == 1
 4 >> 1 == 2
 6 >> 1 == 3
42 >> 3 == 5
0x120 >> 4 == 0x12
0x129 >> 4 == 0x12
0x12f >> 4 == 0x12
0x130 >> 4 == 0x13
```

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is the bitwise left operator, and `>>` is the bitwise right operator.

These shift the value on one side of the equation by the value on the other.

Answer (score 1):

It's converted into binary, and then moved to the left or the right. Like `2 << 3`:

```
0000010
```

becomes:

```
0010000
```

Or 16 if you convert it back.

`>>` is the other way round: `(16 >> 3) === 2`.

Answer (score 1):

These are the binary shift operators. A

As you know, numbers are represented in binary in computers (6 = 110 , 9 = 1001, etc.)

A left bit shift "<<" shifts the binary digits to the left. For instance, `6 << 2` shifts 6 (i.e. 110) two binary digits.

Also note that in a 32-bit environment, 32-bits would be used to represent an integer, so 6 would be:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110`

6 << 2 (6 shifted 2 to the left):

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1000`

6 >> 2 (6 shifted 2 to the right):

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`